# Why does RegExp.exec(...) return undefined for my second parameter?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var re = /{{(.*?)}}|\$\|(.*?)\$\|/;
```

And I am running the following code (produces the same result in Chrome and iOS):

```
re.exec('$|Order.CreateDate$|');
```

I am correctly returned an array, but the second parameter is undefined and the matching parenthesis are at index 3, and I have no idea why? Results as follows:

```
[
    "$|Order.CreateDate$|",
    undefined,
    "Order.CreateDate"
]
```

Comment: _If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: Do you want to merge the 2 alternatives into 1 capturing group? Or just knowing you have 2 is already fine?

Comment: Ideally into just one - I'm guessing that I can do this as follows: `/({{|\$\|)(.*?)(}}|\$\|)/`. But then I'd prefer to do it without two additional capturing groups - is that possible?

Comment: I suggest this: [`(?:{{|\$\|)((?:(?!}}|{{|\$\|).)*)(?:}}|\$\|)`](https://regex101.com/r/vP5lN9/1). Although it is unreadable (well, the symbols you have require escaping, and tempered greedy token has always looked awkward), it ensures the matches without delimiters inside them. If the strings you have allow the other delimiters appear inside the match, this won't work. JS has no support for conditional regex :(

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much!

Comment: @anubhava: I wrote  about that in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because your first captured group is not matching anything using this sub-pattern:

```
{{(.*?)}}
```

Comment: Oh OK - thanks! Even though there's alternation - should it not revert to that?

Comment: Yes there is an alternation but regex has 2 capturing groups and 2nd one is succeeding that's why in resulting: 2nd index is being populated. 0th position is always the complete match.

Comment: Yep just managed to figure that out - ha! Thanks for the quick answer.